# Basic authentication on node.js using curl

Tags: node.js, curl, basic-authentication

I am developing an app and as authentication method I am using Basic authentication. So far everything was working fine but apparently I am still doing something wrong as a new partner indicated.

In particular, commands of the form:

```
curl -v -H 'Authorization: Basic test:test' -H 'APP_KEY: AN-APP-KEY' -H 'APP_SECRET: XyZ' http://localhost:3000/auth
```

succeed, and the headers that I receive on the server are like this:

```
{
"user-agent": "curl/7.37.1",
"host": "localhost:3000",
"accept": "*/*",
"authorization": "Basic test:test",
"app_key": "AN-APP-KEY",
"app_secret": "XyZ"
}
```

On the other hand, a command of the form:

```
curl -v --user 'test:test' -H 'APP_KEY: AN-APP-KEY' -H 'APP_SECRET: XyZ' http://localhost:3000/auth
```

does not succeed. Actually the headers that I can see on the server side are like this:

```
{
"authorization": "Basic dGVzdF9hdXRoOnRlc3Q=",
"user-agent": "curl/7.37.1",
"host": "localhost:3000",
"accept": "*/*",
"app_key": "AN-APP-KEY",
"app_secret": "XyZ"
}
```

So, the question is: Do you know why this happens and how it can be resolved on the server side? Should the second curl command instead be different and why?

Looking forward to your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first example, the one you claim works,  is not actually an implementation of http basic auth. You are passing an Authentication: header but it does not conform to standard. The authentication header should contain the word Basic followed by credentials in base64 coded format. This is what you're seeing in example 2 (if decoding the base64 you get "test_auth:test").

So in order to support basic authentication, the second one is what you need to handle.
To handle this in your server use one of the existing modules such as [basic-auth](https://github.com/jshttp/basic-auth) to have it decode your credentials for you.

Comment: Thank you. Can I ask you one more question in case you know: why do we make the conversion to base64?

Comment: Simply to allow for characters in the password that otherwise wouldn't be allowed in a header.